# Odoo If statement with category

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

Hi I am using Odoo10 and I have some products assigned to categorys. On my Sale Order screen I have 2 selection boxes one is Carpet and the other is Flooring. Below is my code for showing cetain fields

```
@api.onchange('squarebox')
    def _onchange_default_code(self):
      if self.flooring2:
        self.boxes = (self.squaremtr) / (self.squarebox or 1)
        self.squaremtrsold = (self.squarebox or 1) * (self.suggestbox)
```

Instead of using a selection field I was wondering if it is possible to do an IF statement based on Category the product is in. So instead of `if self.flooring2:`something like

if self.productid is in category Carpet:

Answer (score 1):

- First add this two category in Category Master then select this Internal category in Product you want.

**Your XML File :**

```
<record id="category_flooring" model="product.category">
    <field name="name">Flooring</field>
    <field name="type">normal</field>
    <field name="property_cost_method">standard</field>
    <field name="property_valuation">manual_periodic</field>
</record>
<record id="category_carpet" model="product.category">
    <field name="name">Carpet</field>
    <field name="type">normal</field>
    <field name="property_cost_method">standard</field>
    <field name="property_valuation">manual_periodic</field>
</record>
```

- **Now your python code goes like this:-**

```
@api.onchange('product_id')
    def _onchange_default_code(self):
        if self.product_id.categ_id.id == self.env.ref('your_module_name.category_flooring').id:
            #  Your code belongs to flooring category
        elif self.product_id.categ_id.id == self.env.ref('your_module_name.category_carpet').id:
            #  Your code belongs to carpet category
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to show or hide some fields depending on values from other fields of the same record.

To do so use the `invisible` attribute on the form view definition, not a python function. I would use a python function decorated with an `@api.onchange` to calculate other values that depend on `squarebox`.

See for example addons/sale/views/sale_views.xml around line 227:

```
<field name="validity_date" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', 'in', ['sale', 'done'])]}"/>
```

The line above translates to plain English as: Show the `validity_date` field except when the `state` field is either sale or done.